# Media Foundation get encoded bitrate

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation, audio-processing

I am trying to get the encoded bitrate of an audio file (mp4, m4a, aac) using Media Foundation.

What I did is:

```
PROPVARIANT prop;
IMFSourceReader* reader;

MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(filePath, NULL, &reader);
reader->GetPresentationAttribute(MF_SOURCE_READER_MEDIASOURCE, MF_PD_AUDIO_ENCODING_BITRATE,
                                                                                     &prop);
```

The second line ends with an error and with empty PROPVARIAT.

However, when I do:

```
reader->GetPresentationAttribute(MF_SOURCE_READER_MEDIASOURCE, MF_PD_DURATION, &prop);
```

It works fine.

Does anyone know what is the issue and/or are there any other approaches to get the encoded bitrate of an audio track?

Comment: MF_PD_AUDIO_ENCODING_BITRATE is optional as stated in MSDN. I think you'd better GetUINT32 for MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND and MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, and calculate the bitrate from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio bitrate is a property of a track, not of a media file. Hence, you'd normally want to choose a specific track (yes, typically it's the first audio track even if the file is audio-only single track file) and query its attributes.

Presentation description would get you attributes like this (I list just a few relevant):

- Key `MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE`, vValue `MFMediaType_Audio`
- Key `MF_MT_SUBTYPE`, vValue `MFAudioFormat_AAC`
- **Key `MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE`, vValue 125601**
- Key `MF_MT_AAC_AUDIO_PROFILE_LEVEL_INDICATION`, vValue 0
- Key `MF_MT_AAC_PAYLOAD_TYPE`, vValue 0

If you only need an informational value, such as presented by Windows shell:

[image]

and you don't need Media Foundation otherwise (that is, just to access the value), you can use [shell property handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762084) to do this job for you. You would just request [`PKEY_Audio_EncodingBitrate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384862) property and the handler would leverage Media Foundation to retrieve that for you.